# Flex mobile project with sqlite - debugging mode on device, cant find the database

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging, apache-flex, flexbuilder

im creating a mobile project with flex builder for android. It contains a (SQLITE) database. Debugging on desktop working well, ive trying debugging on device its working until the access to database, is breaking, cant find the database.

1.Must i copy the database manualy from my windows7 ....AppData/Roaming/myfolder/to android device? How?

2.Must i set any option in debugger of Flex builder to include the database for debugging on device? How?

3.What is the easyest way? or its not possible?

Comment: do you have code and any error logs

Comment: SQLError: 'Error #3115: SQL Error.', details:'no such table: 'dialogs'', operation:'execute', detailID:'2013 the project is to big to post it here. It working on desktop, only debugging on device not working. i suppose the database is not copyied in debugg mode on the device.

Comment: Try creating a tiny sample project that exhibits the same behavior.  You'll probably find a fix while you're doing that, but if not, you'll have something you can post here.  Without that, it's going to be hard for us to help debug your code.